# How to make gzip xml request/response in php by curl_setopt

Tags: php, xml, gzip

I am using php with curl_setopt to get my xml request and response. Below code i and using for that. But i need to apply GZIP in my request and response comes in GZIP.

Below is the code i using now. But my XML response holders saying i am not sending the GZIP request.

plz update my below code's

```
$xml_request = '<customer>
        <product>computer</product>
        <request>
            <productid>1001</productid>
        </request>
    </customer>';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_request);
    $xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
```

it will use whatever encoding is supported automatically, including gzip

To check if it works correctly, add this code after your curl_exec call:

```
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($xml_response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($xml_response, $header_size);
```

this code before calling curl_exec:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

then echo/var_dump the $header to check if response been sent using gzip

so the code for debugging should look like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($xml_response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($xml_response, $header_size);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($header);
```

Comment: when i apply this, i getting blank response

Comment: do you have $request_url&xml_request defined above the code? does removing CURLOPT_ENCODING return the response? probably I've made a typo somewhere :)

Comment: My server starting using GZIP for my requests only after adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');`. Works like a charm!